# How to make a secure Bluetooth connection to a Raspberry Pi with no user interaction?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

For a project I work on I'm looking for an option to connect a phone to my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ using Bluetooth. I need the connection to be secure, but with no user interaction on the Raspberry Pi, and also with no usage of the phone's Bluetooth adress.
I want the to be able to enter a password using my phone to connect to the Raspberry Pi with no need to grant permission on the Raspberry Pi, but I can't find a way to do it.
So if you know how to do it I would be really happy for a solution, or if you have a better option to establish a secure connection with no user interaction I would also like to hear about it.

I tried to change settings in the main.conf file but it didn't change anything.
I tried to create a BLE peripheral but the code didn't work.
I also tried to use some solutions from here [Bluetoothctl set passkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709583/bluetoothctl-set-passkey/52164888#52164888), but none have worked.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Do you want to use BLE or Bluetooth Classic for this?

Comment: I tried both, but prefer Bluetooth Classic

Comment: And what did not work with the linked Bluetoothctl solutions? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: All of the option require me to permit the connection on the raspberry pi, and it fails to connect afterwards. The phone says it's unable to pair.
Edit: I did manage to connect with the bt-agent method, but it still requires to enter the pin on the raspberry pi

Comment: Today, this type of application is usually solved using NFC technology. Eample: [NFC BLUETOOTH PAIRING](https://phiaton.com/blogs/audio/nfc-bluetooth-pairing-what-is-it-and-what-are-the-benefits)

Comment: NFC is a last resort for the project. I wonder if there's an option to do it without NFC

Comment: If you cannot or do not want to provide any credential data to secure the pairing process, use the simple Bluetooth pairing "Just works" and dispense with the security aspect.

Comment: I thought about it, but it's a project that has to do with medical information. It must have some kind of secure connection

Comment: You have to choose one thing. Simplicity or security. There is no such thing as both together.

Comment: Does the RPi have a screen/display or any other way to show a random 6-digit passkey?

Comment: @Emil doesn't your question also imply that the other device has a keyboard to enter the digits or at least some keys to confirm the passkey?

Comment: Yes. Isn't that ok? From your question you don't want user interaction on the pi, but did not write anything about the phone.

Comment: @Emil I can interact with the raspberry pi while working on the project and choose a password for it. But later I want people to be able to connect to the Pi's Bluetooth with a password and no interaction with the Raspberry Pi, also no screen. Ofc I will let them know the password I chose.
There will be user interaction on the phone

Answer (score 1):

Try btferret with the C server code below. Some combination of KEY_ and PASSKEY_ options may work without Pi user interaction (it depends on the phone). See sections 3.5 and 4.2.2 in the documentation.

https://github.com/petzval/btferret

```
#######################

1, Download

btlib.c
btlib.h
devices.txt

2. Save code below as server.c

3. Compile

gcc server.c btlib.c -o server

4. Run

sudo ./server


########################



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "btlib.h"

int classic_callback(int clientnode,unsigned char *dat,int len);

int main()
  {
     
  if(init_blue("devices.txt") == 0)
    return(0);

  classic_server(ANY_DEVICE,classic_callback,10,KEY_ON | PASSKEY_LOCAL);
  
  // Try various combinations of KEY_ and PASSKEY_ options
  // described in documentation 4.2.2

  // For more security, to only accept connections from a specified device
  // defined as node 4 in devices.txt
  // classic_server(4,classic_callback,10,KEY_ON | PASSKEY_LOCAL);

  // classic_server may have to be called twice -
  // once to pair and second to connect
  
  close_all();
  return(0);
  }
  

int classic_callback(int clientnode,unsigned char *dat,int len)
  {
  int n;
  
  printf("Data = ");
    
  for(n = 0 ; n < len ; ++n)
    printf(" %02X",dat[n]);
  printf("\n");
  
  // Trigger exit from classic_server by:
  // return(SERVER_EXIT);  
  
  // On the first call here dat[] must be the password
  // or return(SERVER_EXIT) terminates the connection
  

  return(SERVER_CONTINUE);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth does not provide any security mechanism based on a pre-set password. The nearest you have is the random passkey pairing method where one device generates a random password (which must be newly generated every time in order to get the desired security properties), shows it on the screen and the user then inputs this number on the other device.

Solutions like HomeKit and Matter (smart home protocols) use a [PAKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement), e.g. Spake2+, to implement security based on a pre-set passcode, which is printed on the device. They run this key exchange on top of (unencrypted) Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Out-Of-Band Pairing

Comment: That typically requires NFC, which the OP didn't want to use.

Comment: Hardware like NFC or USB are ways to support OOB, but other software ways are also possible, e.g., using sharing OOB data by means of secured TCP/IP is also possible.