# How to automatically accept bluetooth pair request without popping confirmation dialogue box in raspberry pi through terminal or through SSH

Tags: ssh, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, pairing

I need to accept the bluetooth pair request in raspberry pi without manual confirmation. My task is to send a pair request from Android phone to raspberry pi 3 and to automatically accept the pair request based on MAC address of mobile, But it asking manual confirmation in raspberry pi, how can i automatically accept the request,

when i pass the below commands
.bluetoothctl
.power on
.discoverable on
and made a request from Android device, manual confirmation is asking for authentication

how to achieve this, without manual confirmation

Comment: It is 3B or 3B+?

Comment: @toyotaSupra its model 3B

Comment: Have you tried setting the bluetoothctl agent to `NoInputNoOutput`? More information at: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123830/121848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ukBaz suggested, you can do this by setting your IO capabilities to NoInputNoOutput.I would recommend sending the following sequence of commands to achieve this:-

```
sudo btmgmt power off
sudo btmgmt discov on
sudo btmgmt connectable on
sudo btmgmt pairable on
sudo btmgmt power on
sudo btmgmt io-cap 3
```

The last command sets your IO capabilities to NoInputNoOutput, and the numberical values correspond to the following:-

```
0       DisplayOnly
1       DisplayYesNo
2       KeyboardOnly
3       NoInputNoOutput
4       KeyboardDisplay
```

You can then set this with bluetoothctl as well via the following commands:-

```
bluetoothctl --agent NoInputNoOutput
```

Have a look at the links below for more info:-

- [Raspberry Pi BLE pairing/encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147384/raspberry-ble-encryption-pairing/62242352#62242352)
- [BLE pairing the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/12/19/tutorial-ble-pairing-the-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-with-hexiwear/)
- [Bluetoothctl set passkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709583/bluetoothctl-set-passkey)

Comment: "bluetoothctl --agent NoInputNoOutput" via python i was unable to execute this command, does i need to give any alternate permissions to this -- @Youssif

Comment: Can you clarify the issue that you are seeing please? What error response did you get? Also, bluetoothctl is a SHELL command, in other words you shouldn't be running it via Python unless I am missing something.

Comment: I'm trying to execute the command "bluetoothctl --agent NoINputNoOutput" which changes the agent to "NoInputNoOutput" manually i can able to execute the command i terminal, if i tried to execute the command through python it's not changing the agent, and giving output "no agent is registered"

Comment: OK I think I understand now. In this case I am not sure what is happening, but my recommendation is that you post a separate question about this given that it is unrelated to the current one. In the new question you can add the exact python commands that you are using in case there is an issue there.