# Raspberry Pi Bluetooth: Enable legacy pairing / connection without PIN input

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, dbus, bluez, bluetooth-gatt

For a few days I'm desperately trying to configure Bluetooth legacy pairing on my Raspberry Pi. Unfortunately I hadn't had any success until today. I tried countless tutorials/posts on several forums but no one worked.

Can anyone give me an up to date method that worked in your case? I noticed that almost all posts about this topic are at least 2 years old, which doesn't make it easier to get to a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this from the command line, all you need to do is launch bluetoothctl with no input/no output capabilities. See below the recommended sequence of commands:-

```
sudo btmgmt power off
sudo btmgmt discov on
sudo btmgmt connectable on
sudo btmgmt pairable on
sudo btmgmt power on
sudo btmgmt io-cap 3
```

The last command sets your IO capabilities to NoInputNoOutput, and the numberical values correspond to the following:-

```
0       DisplayOnly
1       DisplayYesNo
2       KeyboardOnly
3       NoInputNoOutput
4       KeyboardDisplay
```

Finally, launch bluetoothctl as follows:-

```
bluetoothctl --agent NoInputNoOutput
```

Some references:-

- [Raspberry Pi BLE pairing/encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147384/raspberry-ble-encryption-pairing/62242352#62242352)
- [What Bluetoothctl agents are there](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107400/what-bluetoothctl-agents-are-there/123830#123830)
- [bluetoothctl set passkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709583/bluetoothctl-set-passkey)

Comment: You just made my day, thanks a lot. It works! Is there any possibility of authorizing all bluetooth services on the raspberry pi as well? If I now connect my phone to the Raspberry Pi, I still have to type in "yes" to authorize several bluetooth services